# How to pull new files from git master?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

Hi I have been scouring all the forums and search engines for doing what I thought to be simple. I am trying to pull all the changes from my master git repo into a remote branch. It does that but does not pull in the new files created. How on earth can I make sure that new files are added to the branch with

```
git pull
```

I tried:

```
git checkout master newfile.html
```

and

```
git checkout HEAD -- newfile.html
```

I thought that by default 'pull' would just update everything from the master new or not new, but it is obviously not the case. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Show us the output after pull.

Comment: are you sure that the files were pushed in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to do

```
git pull origin branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for your replies. It seems to have worked with all 3:

```
git checkout master
Already on 'master'
git merge master
git pull


Enter passphrase for key '/home/seytunn/.ssh/id_dsa': 
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 7), reused 7 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
From github.com:seytunn/my_rnnn
6fc621c..64afc61  master     -> origin/master
Updating 6fc621c..64afc61
Fast-forward
css/main.css |   21 +++++++-
require.html  |  152    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 172 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 require.html
```

Comment: if answers have helped you, please *upvote* them; make sure to *accept* the answer that actually solved your problem best (it seems that you haven't ever accepted any answer to all of your questions so far; make sure that you have read the [tour] before using [so])

Comment: Glad you got it working, but it seems like you're mixing up some of your terminology. If you've only got a master branch and not anything else, you've done nothing different here than what you posted in your question. Read the [GitHub glossary](https://help.github.com/articles/github-glossary/) and [this article](http://betterexplained.com/articles/aha-moments-when-learning-git/) for a useful introduction to git, and learn about local versus remote repositories.